# PHP MYSQL select * with this value with between these dates

Tags: php, mysql, date-range, mysql-num-rows

I'm trying to select a list of `customers` that have entered a specific `voucher code`, within certain `dates`.

Here is my code with my latest attempt:

```
$result = mysql_query(
          "SELECT COUNT(members.voucher_code)
           FROM members WHERE YEAR(date_started) = 2014
           members.voucher_code = 'new'");
$count = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $count;
```

I would like it to show all voucher codes that have the value of `new` which have been submitted `between 01/01/14 - 31/12/14`

I've tried a number of things but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Comment: What format is the column 'date_started'?

Comment: `where year(date_Started) = 2014 and voucher_code = 'new'`

Comment: Use `AND` keyword after 2014...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(members.voucher_code) 
FROM members 
WHERE 
   members.voucher_code = 'new' AND
   date_started BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct query should be like:

```
SELECT COUNT(members.voucher_code)
FROM members
WHERE date_started > 'from_date' AND date_started < 'to_date'
```

Here `from_date` and `to_date` is the date passed by you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(members.voucher_code)
FROM members
WHERE YEAR(date_started) = 2014 and members.voucher_code = 'new'");
```

You are missing the `AND` condition in your query.